# How to get the URL for a document in Alfresco using the PHP CMIS API?

Tags: php, alfresco, cmis, ecm, apache-chemistry

I have already constructed a query that returns all of the relevant documents that I may need from the alfresco repository. But I don't know how to link to them so that I can access them.

Once I retrieve the list of documents I tried using the getContentStream() function but that requires that I input credentials into a prompt. I need a way to access that document externally without re-authenticating. I already authenticate and connect using the PHP CMIS API, the users will not have alfresco accounts themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write a proxy that will fetch the content stream on the user's behalf using the existing CMIS session, then stream it back to the client making the request.

Jeff

Comment: I am not familiar with the process of creating a proxy to stream the content to the client... Are there any references or examples you can share with me? Also it seems that there should be a way around this by using Guest users or somehow granting public access, but I'm not able to do this. I can invite the user Guest, but in Share I can't log on to accept the invite and in Explorer it returns an error.

Comment: If you want to allow Guest access to a piece of content, navigate to the content through the repository view (not through the site's document library) and then click "Manage Permissions". Now add Guest with Consumer access. When you return the download URL to the user, add &guest=true to the end of the URL.